# Pandas to_sql index with MultiIndex columns

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I'm trying to write a DataFrame that has MultiIndex columns to an MS SQL database. The index gets output as NULL. If I have just single columns, it works fine.

```
l1 = ['foo', 'bar']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([l1, l2])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,6)), index=[1,2,3], columns=cols)
df.to_sql('test', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

[How it looks in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miuOm.png)

Is this a bug or do I need to do something else to properly write the index?

Comment: Does ```df.to_sql('test', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)``` do what you want?

Comment: No, that just writes it without the index at all.

Comment: Was there a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate each of the first levels of your dataframe:

```py
l1 = ['foo', 'bar']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([l1, l2])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,6)), index=[1,2,3], columns=cols)
pd.concat([df['foo'],df['bar']]).to_sql('test', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

This results in this table:

```sql
index                a                      b                      c
-------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1                    0.803555407060559      0.0185295254735488     0.702949767792433
2                    0.257823384796912      0.985716269729717      0.749719964181681
3                    0.909115063376081      0.236242172285058      0.932813789580215
1                    0.898527697819921      0.874431627680823      0.805393798630385
2                    0.97537971906356       0.319221893730643      0.584449093938984
3                    0.678625747581189      0.606321574437647      0.437746301372623
```

If you want something closer to the SQL table example you link to, you could use merge and suffix each column:

```py
l1 = ['foo', 'bar']
l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([l1, l2])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3,6)), index=[1,2,3], columns=cols)
pd.merge(df['foo'], df['bar'],
         right_index=True, left_index=True,
         suffixes=['_' + s for s in df.columns.levels[0].to_list()]
         ).to_sql('test', conn, if_exists='replace')
```

That will get you:

```sql
index                a_bar                  b_bar                  c_bar                  a_foo                  b_foo                  c_foo
-------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1                    0.989229457189419      0.0759829132299624     0.172846406489083      0.154227020200058      0.386003904079867      0.733402063652856
2                    0.839971061213949      0.975761261358953      0.252917398323633      0.0881692963378311     0.560403977291031      0.806066332511174
3                    0.914544313717528      0.921965094934119      0.821869705625485      0.337292501691803      0.125899685577926      0.527830968883373
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit the same problem. Pandas now allows an index or column multiindex to be flattened with

`df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()`

Do that first, then

`df.to_sql('test', conn, if_exists='replace')`

The index is written and the column names are the same as your SQL output.

If you don't like the strange SQL columns names another option is to modify the pandas column names instead by joining both levels, ie.

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(i) for i in df.columns.to_flat_index()]
print(df.columns)
Index(['foo_a', 'foo_b', 'foo_c', 'bar_a', 'bar_b', 'bar_c'], dtype='object')
```