# Opposite of Pandas "to_flat_index()"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with MultiIndex columns, which I'm writing to an SQL database. To write to the database nicely I have to flatten the MultiIndex (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406162/3087409)), but this means when I read from the database I want to reconstruct the MultiIndex.

`df.columns` before flattening:

```
MultiIndex([(   'foo',  'bar'),
            ('part 2', 'spam')]
)
```

Dataframe after `df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()`:

```
Index([    ('foo', 'bar'),
       ('part 2', 'spam')],
dtype='object')
```

`df.columns` as read from the database (`df = pd.read_sql_table('df', connection)`)

```
Index(['('foo', 'bar')', '('part 2', 'spam')'],
dytpe='object')
```

Is there a way to reconstruct the original MultiIndex from the latest version of the dataframe?

Comment: this `['('foo', 'bar')', '('part 2', 'spam')']` is not a valid python syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation of the multiindex has been converted into a string by saving and loading it into the Database. In order to reconstruct it you can parse it using `str.extract`

```
extracted_names = df.columns.str.extract(r"\(\'(.*)\', \'(.*)\'\)")    
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(extracted_names ,names=[None,None])
```

What this basically does is search for the pattern `('`*a*`', '`*b*`')` and return a dataframe containing *a* and *b* for all columns. This can the be transformed into a multiindex with `pd.MultiIndex.from_frame`